# How to specify what directory to import a package from in Python?

Tags: python, configuration, package

I want to install updated packages in another directory and have Python grab the updated package instead of the older package.

I'm trying to find a way that I can specify which directory to import for when there are multiple identical packages in `sys.path`.

I started by running this code to make sure that the path for the second module is present:

```
import sys
print('\n'.join(sys.path))
```

Both paths are shown, so I know that Python could find the package from either location.

I run this to see what path Python is using:

```
import statsmodels
print(statsmodels.__file__)
```

It is using the path of the out of date version.

I've been looking into using `importlib` but I haven't figured out how to make that work.

I'm just looking for a way to import a package from a specified path, even when the package exists in another directory in `sys.path`.

Comment: Did you try this solution?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder

Comment: @mrbTT I did try that solution.  I'll admit that I don't understand entirely the technicalities of what it is doing, but I did try to implement it unsuccessfully.

Comment: Oh, ok it simply says that when importing stuff it should also consider the mentioned folder. Let's say this. Consider the root folder of your script is `folder_script`. The updated python files you want to import are in a new folder inside `folder_script`(as in `folder_script\folder_i_got_permissions\updated_scripts`) or folder before (as there is `master_folder\folder_script` and the updated are in `master_folder\updated_scripts`) ?

Comment: @mrbTT I got it!  I wasn't implementing it correctly because I didn't understand it correctly.  Thank you.  You can put a solution if you want and I'll accept it.

Comment: Okie, added answer explaining the mentioned solution for other people that might land here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as discussed in the commend you'd neeed to implement [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder). With that to further explain what it does, it points to another folder to consider files to import. Considering the mentioned code:

```
# some_file.py (this is this script you're running)
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/application/app/folder')

import file_name_inside_the_folder_above
```

You'd let the first argument `0` untouched and just edit the second argument, pointing to which folder the script you have access is. Then you just import as the it's file name.